# Scrape text from a lightbox using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, casperjs

Is it possible for one to scrape text from a lightbox using scrapy? On SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498550/scraping-text-from-lightbox-using-casperjs) question deals with scraping a lightbox using CasperJS. I was wondering if the same thing is possible using Scrapy?

Comment: I would reason about using Selenium + Scrapy to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the output of `response.body` and from there I figured out how to access the elements of the lightbox.